# If $\frac{\cos^4\theta}{\cos^2\phi}+\frac{\sin^4\theta}{\sin^2\phi}=1$, show $\frac{\cos^4\phi}{\cos^2\theta} +\frac{\sin^4\phi}{\sin^2\theta}=1$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\dfrac{\cos^4\theta}{\cos^2\phi}+\dfrac{\sin^4\theta}{\sin^2\phi}=1$, prove that $\dfrac{\cos^4\phi}{\cos^2\theta} +\dfrac{\sin^4\phi}{\sin^2\theta}=1$.

Unable to move further ...request you to please suggest how to proceed ..Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $ x = \cos \theta$, $y = \cos \phi$.

Show by expansion (and clearing denominators) that both equations are equivalent to $x^4 - 2x^2 y^2 + y^4 =0$, hence these statements are equivalent to each other.

Note: This shows that the condition is satisfied iff $x = \pm y$. This is not required, but very strongly hinted at in the question.

Answer (score 2):

We can Write
$$\frac{Cos^4\theta}{Cos^2\phi}+\frac{Sin^4\theta}{Sin^2\phi}=Cos^2\phi+Sin^2\phi$$ $\implies$
$$ \left(Cos^2\phi-\frac{Cos^4\theta}{Cos^2\phi}\right)+\left(Sin^2\phi-\frac{Sin^4\theta}{Sin^2\phi}\right)=0$$ $\implies$
$$ Cos^4\phi+Sin^4\phi=Cos^4\theta+Sin^4\theta$$ $\implies$
$$ Sin\phi Cos\phi=Sin\theta Cos\theta \implies Sin(2\phi)=Sin(2\theta)$$ So

$$\phi=k\pi+\theta ,\: k \in \mathbb{Z}$$ So

$$ Cos\phi=(-1)^k Cos\theta, Sin\phi=(-1)^k Sin\theta$$ Finally the Result follows..

Comment: nice to see another method. But, how have you reached at $ Sin\phi Cos\phi=Sin\theta Cos\theta$ from $ Cos^4\phi+Sin^4\phi=Cos^4\theta+Sin^4\theta$? as to me $$ \cos^4\phi+\sin^4\phi=(\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi)^2-2\cos^2\phi\sin^2\phi=1-\frac{\sin^22\phi}2=1-\frac{1-\cos4\phi}4$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I think what he did was $1 - 2 \sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta = \sin^4 \theta + \cos^4 \theta = \sin^4 \phi + \cos^4 \phi = 1 - 2 \sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta$. Technically, we have $ sin ^2 ( 2 \theta) = \sin^2 (2 \phi)$, I'm not sure how he got rid of the squares.

Comment: Can you explain how to go from the second line to the third line? Note that if you have double implication arrows, then the result follows immediately.

Comment: getting rid of squares doesn't matter, because even if $$Sin(2\phi)=-Sin(2\theta)$$, result will be the same since we have squares and 4th powers in actual expression for which we need to find its value.